# Unable to set Visible property of the PivotItem class

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, date, pivot

I wrote a VBA script to loop over several pivot tables and change the month according to user input. It worked a few times during testing it, but now it suddenly throws out the error in the title. I can´t figure out why.

```
Sub change_pivot()
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim Ws As Worksheet:
Dim p As PivotTable:
Dim f As PivotField:
Dim i As PivotItem, s$
Dim i2 As PivotItem
Dim Message, Title, Default, MyValue
Dim curr_year As Integer
Dim pvt_tables As Variant

Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
Set Ws = Wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set p = Ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set f = p.PivotFields("Month")
Set g = p.PivotFields("Year")

curr_year = year(Date)

pvt_tables = Array("1", "10", "3", "12", "11", "4", "5")

Message = "Enter a month value in the folowing format: (01)"
Title = "Insert Month"    ' Set title.
Default = "01"    ' Set default.
' Display message, title, and default value.
s = InputBox(Message, Title, Default)



Message = "Is the year correct?"
Title = "check year"    ' Set title.
Default = curr_year   ' Set default.
' Display message, title, and default value.
y = InputBox(Message, Title, Default)

        
For Each x In pvt_tables
    Set p = Ws.PivotTables("PivotTable" & x)
    Set f = p.PivotFields("Month")


' change months
    With f
        For Each i In .PivotItems
            If i.Name <> s Then
                i.Visible = False
            Else:
                i.Visible = True
            End If
        Next
    End With
Next
```

It doesn´t work with the loop over the array and without it as well. Any ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: You do this in your loop `Set p = Ws.PivotTables("PivotTable" & x)` but then you don't use `p` ?

Comment: p is "inlcuded" in f. I could´ve done this in ine step but I used 2 for some reason

Comment: But f only points to `PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Month")` Changing `p` later doesn't automatically change `f`...

Comment: Okay, I maybe I don´t get it. I edited the code above. For some reason it worked once, but when I tried it a second time, I got the same error again... Where do I have to use p again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have at least one `PivotItem` visible - you get that error when you try to hide the last visible one (so it fails unless the items you're showing comes *before* the last one you try to hide).

Try something like this:

```vb
Sub change_pivot()
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim p As PivotTable
    Dim f As PivotField
    Dim i As PivotItem, mnth As String, yr As String
    Dim i2 As PivotItem
    Dim pvt_tables As Variant, x, pi As PivotItem
    
    Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set Ws = Wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    mnth = InputBox("Enter a month number", "Month", "01")
    If Len(mnth) = 1 Then mnth = "0" & mnth 'add leading zero if not entered
    
'    yr = InputBox("Is the year correct?", _
'                 "Insert Month", Year(Date))
    
    pvt_tables = Array("1", "10", "3", "12", "11", "4", "5")
    
    For Each x In pvt_tables
        Set p = Ws.PivotTables("PivotTable" & x)
        With p.PivotFields("Month")
            On Error Resume Next
            Set pi = .PivotItems(mnth) 'check the entered item exists
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not pi Is Nothing Then
                pi.Visible = True         'first set desired item visible
                For Each i In .PivotItems 'then hide the others
                    If i.Name <> mnth Then i.Visible = False
                Next
            Else
                MsgBox "No item exists for '" & mnth & "'"
            End If
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, that was exactly the problem, thank you for the great solution!